# Zend Framework 2 : set reason phrase for error 404

Tags: php, http-headers, zend-framework2, http-status-code-404

I want my controller to return a 404 response when a model is not found and I want to specify a custom message, not the default "`The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request.`"

I have tried specifying the `reason` in the `ViewModel`, setting the `reasonPhrase` from the response object... nothing seems to work. I am currently investigating how I can prevent the default behaviour, but if someone know before I do, that would just be great. (Perhaps there's a better way than the one I would find anyhow, too.)

Here is what I have, which does not work :

```
 $userModel = $this->getUserModel();
 if (empty($userModel)) {
     $this->response->setStatusCode(404);
     $this->response->setReasonPhrase('error-user-not-found');
     return new ViewModel(array(
         'content' => 'User not found',
     ));
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: "The requested controller was unable to dispatch the request." is returned by page not found event handler, not your controller.

Comment: See the 404 template. If you use Application module, see Application/view/error/404.phtml switch ($this->reason) { ... }

Comment: @dphn, yes, the point is that I set the reason in the controller and it gets overridden in between the rendering phase.

Comment: @imel96, can you elaborate on that? The comment in itself does not help to solve the question here.

Comment: Controllers are dispatched by EventManager at EVENT_DISPATCH event but only if it can be dispatched. If it can't, then an EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR will be triggered, you're code won't be executed and it will show view/error/404.phtml. Otoh, your code looks fine to me if the controller was dispatched. Sorry, if not answering, I'd guess it's a routing problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are confusing the reasponphrase and the reason variable passed on to the view. The reasonphrase is part of the http status code, like "Not Found" for 404. You probably don't want to change that.

Like @dphn is saying, I would recommend throwing your own Exception and attach a listener to the `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` which decides what to respond.

**To get you started:**

*Controller*

```
public function someAction()
{
    throw new \Application\Exception\MyUserNotFoundException('This user does not exist');
}
```

*Module*

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $events = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $events->attach(
        MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR,
        function(MvcEvent $e) {
            $exception = $e->getParam('exception');
            if (! $exception instanceof \Application\Exception\MyUserNotFoundException) {
                return;
            }

            $model = new ViewModel(array(
                'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
                'reason' => 'error-user-not-found',
                'exception' => $exception,
            ));
            $model->setTemplate('error/application_error');
            $e->getViewModel()->addChild($model);

            $response = $e->getResponse();
            $response->setStatusCode(404);

            $e->stopPropagation();

            return $model;
        },
        100
    );
}
```

*error/application_error.phtml*

```
<h1><?php echo 'A ' . $this->exception->getStatusCode() . ' error occurred ?></h1>
<h2><?php echo $this->message ?></h2>  
<?php
switch ($this->reason) {
    case 'error-user-not-found':
      $reasonMessage = 'User not found';
      break;
}
echo $reasonMessage;
```

*module.config.php*

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'error/application_error' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/application_error.phtml',
),
```